# jQuery event priority

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which I bind more than one event handlers:

```
<div id="info">
    <button class="action-delete" type="button">Delete</button>
</div>


$("#info").on("click", ".action-delete", function() {
    $.event.trigger({
        type: "application",
        message: {
            name: "item-delete",
            item: $("#info").data("item")
        }
    });
});
```

Then I want the user to make sure before the delete operation is done, since there are so many elements with `action-delete` working for different models, so I tried to inject the following scripts to the page(from another js file):

```
$(document).on("click", ".action-delete", function(e) {
    return confirm("Sure to delete?");
})
```

However I found that event the confirm window displayed, the `delete` operation is still completed before the user choose.

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: I believe event handlers are run FIFO, so you would need to add your first-event-handler before the other one is added (this means including it before the other is seen by the browser). However, I bet there's a cleaner way to do this, like using a `data-confirm='Sure to delete?'` and detect and show/block if that attribute is set. That way you're not doing goofy things like this.

Comment: In fact, I have tried to add the event to `document` before the `#info`,but seems  not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your confirm call here:

```
$(document).on("click", ".action-delete", function(e) {
    return confirm("Sure to delete?");
})
```

It should be something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".action-delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default behavior
    var conf = confirm("Sure to delete?");
    if(conf == true){
      $("#info").trigger( "click" ); //trigger click event for delete
    }
});
```

Plus I would recommend removing the click event from the parent div. Instead make a delete function and let the confirm dialog ('yes') trigger the function.